# Overlayfs: restore removed or changed file from "lower"

Tags: linux, filesystems, openwrt, overlayfs

OpenWrt uses overlayfs

```
# mount | grep overlay
/dev/ubi0_2 on /overlay type ubifs (rw,noatime)
overlayfs:/overlay on / type overlay (rw,noatime,lowerdir=/,upperdir=/overlay/upper,workdir=/overlay/work)
```

Somehow real lowerdir is `/rom`

```
# mount | grep rom
mtd:ubi_rootfs on /rom type squashfs (ro,relatime)
```

**How to restore file to make it the as in `/rom`?** Remove records from overlays: whiteouts and opaque dirs.

**Workaround**

```
cp /rom/path/to/file /overlay/upper/path/to/file
```

Comment: Similar question but about AUFS https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92287/aufs-whiteout-removal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove file from `/overlay/upper`, and then remount rootfs.

```
rm /overlay/upper/my/file
mount -o remount /
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I figured the first command myself then was going to reboot the router, but remount is enough apparently and much faster.

Comment: It might be even enough just to remount the overlayfs instead of the full rootfs.